# Using jQuery prev() method to grab text of H2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Can't seem to get this working. Any ideas?

I'm trying to grab the text that appears between `<h2></h2>` while working with the input field as a starting location.

jQuery:

```
$(".title input").each(function(){
    alert( $(this).prev('h2').text() );
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="tabbertab">
    <h2>English (US)</h2>
    <div class="title">
        <div>
            <label for="title">Title *</label>
        </div>
        <input id="title[en_US]" type="text" name="title[en_US]" value="" class="error">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".title input").each(function(){
    alert( $(this).parent().prev('h2').text() );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was ready to skip this and use another method. You saved me.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.prev()` accesses siblings. By adding `.parent()` to the chain you access siblings of the parent element.

```
$(".title input").each(function() {
    alert( $(this).parent().prev('h2').text() );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4BvJc/

Comment: Thanks! I thought it might be something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("h2").each(function(i, obj){            
     alert(obj.textContent);                
});
```

Try something like this